# how to get xml file form server

Tags: php, xml, deserialization

I want to get value from file type *.xml.
I have problem, because file is type *.php.

File name.php for example has value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pairs>
    <pair>
        <name>EURUSD</name>
        <bid>1.11947</bid>
        <ask>1.11967</ask>
    </pair>
</pairs>
```

I don't know how deserialize this file.

I use:
`$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://page_with_file/file.php');`

I have message:
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: `simplexml_load_file(file.php)`

Comment: File is on server: https://page_with_file/file.php